# GCP Folder cannot be deleted as it contains active resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Trying to delete a folder in GCP but get the error,

> Folder cannot be deleted as it contains active resources. Only empty folders can be deleted.

I suspect there are some hidden resources connected to the folder but I can't figure out what they are (so I can delete them).

Comment: Look into: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview The CLI can list assets in your folder.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this there were firewall policies attached to the folders, one must have to remove the associations of firewall-policies and then magic happens and you will be able to delete the folder.

I want to remove fld-staging folder then I need to remove the associated firewall-policy to delete the folder:
[image: I want to remove fld-staging folder then I need to remove the associated firewall-policy to delete the folder]

Comment: Add on solution for people who come here (since I had the same symptom, but different cause it turned out, but this is top Google result.)

The issue for me was that there was a hidden script in the undelete-able folders and no obvious way to show hidden scripts. 

The solution was

-click on filter
-select filter by "parent-id'
-put in the id of the undelete-able folder

Now I could see the hidden script, delete it, and delete the parent folders, and could go ahead with deleting the google workspace account.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you are facing an issue while deleting the folder and suspecting there are some hidden resources connected to the folder.

First thing in order to delete the folder you need to have Folder Admin or the Folder Editor role.

Follow the commands below to  list the folders underneath a folder

1. `gcloud resource-manager folders list --folder <Folder ID>`

2. `gcloud resource-manager folders list --organization <Org ID>`

3. `gcloud projects list --filter=" parent.id: <Parent folder ID/ Organization ID>`

Once you identified active resources connected to the folder then finally you can run the below command to delete the folder.

```bash
gcloud resource-manager folders delete <FOLDER_ID>
```

For further reading please follow the links below:

- [Viewing or listing folders and projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders#viewing_or_listing_folders_and_projects)

Comment: thanks for input but no projects are listed. This is the same for both gcloud and the Console. As said before I suspect there are some hidden items like log sinks etc. but I can't find out what it is. Can projects tagged for deletion still count as active in a folder?

Comment: tried this.. but couldnt get it to delete. on CLI i am getting `FOLDER_TO_DELETE_NON_EMPTY_VIOLATION`

Comment: another thing I noticed https://imgur.com/a/fmEMhVj was the `{resourceName}` placeholder in this screenshot.

Comment: Maybe this link could help? [Troubleshoot IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/troubleshoot-access), as any resource could be blocked by an IAM permission and not be shown on resources list.

Comment: Additional good reference to complement the answer and suggestions above [here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-dev/c/sfkbt3nLosk).

Comment: Only items listed in the folder are the two standard LogSinks but I am having a hard time to delete them...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any resources listed here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/asset-inventory/policies

If you have, shut them down and try deleting your folder.

Comment: `Asset Inventory` console (inside IAM console) doesn't seem to contain Firewall Policies which, like mentioned in the answer by @markus-meyer and @fahad-khan, is the culprit in my case.